# Tests folders keeps creating in the same directory in .NET 6

Tags: .net-core, xunit, .net-6.0

I have a .NET 6 web api project `main` and inside that I have a folder named `Tests` where I keep all my tests, the solutions looks like this: 
`main.sln`:

```
Microsoft Visual Studio Solution File, Format Version 12.00
# Visual Studio Version 16
VisualStudioVersion = 16.0.30114.105
MinimumVisualStudioVersion = 10.0.40219.1
Project("{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}") = "main", "main.csproj", "{218486FE-31A5-45A1-A6EC-3AD4D3ED9E6D}"
EndProject
Project("{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}") = "Tests", "Tests\Tests.csproj", "{08294007-70CB-4095-847B-1219FA1E7DBA}"
EndProject
Global
    GlobalSection(SolutionConfigurationPlatforms) = preSolution
        Debug|Any CPU = Debug|Any CPU
        Release|Any CPU = Release|Any CPU
    EndGlobalSection
    GlobalSection(SolutionProperties) = preSolution
        HideSolutionNode = FALSE
    EndGlobalSection
    GlobalSection(ProjectConfigurationPlatforms) = postSolution
        {218486FE-31A5-45A1-A6EC-3AD4D3ED9E6D}.Debug|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Debug|Any CPU
        {218486FE-31A5-45A1-A6EC-3AD4D3ED9E6D}.Debug|Any CPU.Build.0 = Debug|Any CPU
        {218486FE-31A5-45A1-A6EC-3AD4D3ED9E6D}.Release|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Release|Any CPU
        {218486FE-31A5-45A1-A6EC-3AD4D3ED9E6D}.Release|Any CPU.Build.0 = Release|Any CPU
        {08294007-70CB-4095-847B-1219FA1E7DBA}.Debug|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Debug|Any CPU
        {08294007-70CB-4095-847B-1219FA1E7DBA}.Debug|Any CPU.Build.0 = Debug|Any CPU
        {08294007-70CB-4095-847B-1219FA1E7DBA}.Release|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Release|Any CPU
        {08294007-70CB-4095-847B-1219FA1E7DBA}.Release|Any CPU.Build.0 = Release|Any CPU
    EndGlobalSection
EndGlobal
```

`main.csproj`:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <RootNamespace>cuzzle_api</RootNamespace>
    <IsTestProject>false</IsTestProject>

    <GenerateAssemblyInfo>false</GenerateAssemblyInfo>
    <GenerateTargetFrameworkAttribute>false</GenerateTargetFrameworkAttribute>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer" Version="6.0.5" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens" Version="6.17.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore" Version="6.2.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Filters" Version="7.0.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt" Version="6.17.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="xunit" Version="2.4.1" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

and `Tests.csproj`

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>

    <IsPackable>false</IsPackable>
    <IsTestProject>true</IsTestProject>

    <GenerateAssemblyInfo>false</GenerateAssemblyInfo>   
    <GenerateTargetFrameworkAttribute>false</GenerateTargetFrameworkAttribute>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk" Version="16.11.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="xunit" Version="2.4.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="xunit.runner.visualstudio" Version="2.4.3">
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="coverlet.collector" Version="3.1.0">
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
    </PackageReference>
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\main.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

The thing is every time I run the tests, folders bin and obj from `Tests` are being created recursevely like this:

```
~/main/bin/Debug/net6.0/Tests/bin/Debug/net6.0/Tests/bin/Debug/net6.0/Tests/bin/Debug/net6.0/Tests
```

What am I doing wrong with my solution or csproj files? or is it ok to be created like this?

Comment: Why is that a problem? In other words what is this preventing you from doing?

Comment: Is the `Tests` project a sub-directory in the `Main` project? If so, move the `Test` project up one level to where the solution file sits.

Comment: @tymtam it keeps creating folders, till a moment when it throws bunch of warnings and I simply cannot build the project unless I delete the `bin` folder